# How to Implement thermal printer in a React app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, printing, frontend, thermal-printer

I need to implement thermal printer functionality in my React app. I have tried using packages such as 'node-thermal-printer,' but we are unable to utilize these node packages as they do not seem to work with React. How can we solve this problem?

I need to print my order details in JSON format to a KOT (Kitchen Order Ticket) thermal printer.

Comment: I think you could install that package in your backend and make the calls from the react app to the backend app.

Comment: Check this [link](https://github.com/seokju-na/react-thermal-printer)

Comment: @Klian Yes. I'm also thinking the same thing

Comment: @ShaikhFaizan React-thermal-printer doesn't have a high number of weekly downloads.